# FileNotFoundException when calling HttpURLConnection getInputStream

Tags: android

I have an app which i want to update from my private server. The code below should download the new apk file from the server and write it to sdcard where the app can update itself from.

I'm getting a FileNotFoundException. The file does exist on the server.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Thanks

```
public void updateApp(String version){
        try {

             version = version.trim();
             String urlWithVersion = "http://cfweb.yourofficeanywhere.co.uk/entryactivityv" + version + ".apk"; 


              URL url = new URL(urlWithVersion);
              HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              c.setRequestMethod("GET");
              c.setDoOutput(true);
              c.connect();

              Log.e(TAG, " HttpURLConnection = connected");

              String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/";
              File file = new File(PATH);
              file.mkdirs();
              Log.e(TAG, "mkdirs()");
              File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
              Log.e(TAG, "fos");

              InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

              Log.e(TAG, "c.getInputStream()");

              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              int len1 = 0;
              while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "update file size = " + len1);
                  fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
              }
              Log.e(TAG, "update file size = " + len1);
              fos.close();
              is.close();


              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              NfcscannerActivity.this.startActivity(intent);



          } catch (Exception e) {

              Log.e(TAG, "update error = " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));


          }
    }  //end of updateApp
```

.

```
09-10 16:00:59.504: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814):  HttpURLConnection = connected
09-10 16:00:59.504: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814): mkdirs()
09-10 16:00:59.504: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814): fos
09-10 16:00:59.644: E/MP-Decision(2194): Update arg 1

09-10 16:01:00.674: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814): update error = java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://cfweb.yourofficeanywhere.co.uk/entryactivityv33.apk
09-10 16:01:00.674: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
09-10 16:01:00.674: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814):    at com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcscannerActivity.updateApp(NfcscannerActivity.java:6353)
09-10 16:01:00.674: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814):    at com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcscannerActivity$AsyncUpdateApp.doInBackground(NfcscannerActivity.java:6317)
09-10 16:01:00.674: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814):    at com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcscannerActivity$AsyncUpdateApp.doInBackground(NfcscannerActivity.java:1)
09-10 16:01:00.674: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-10 16:01:00.674: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-10 16:01:00.674: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-10 16:01:00.674: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-10 16:01:00.674: E/NfcscannerActivity(18814):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

Comment: try checking the connection response code after your c.connect();if (c.getResponseCode()!=200)
   {
    Log.e(TAG,"Http request "+remoteFileName+" failed: "+connection.getResponseMessage());
   }

Comment: have you try after removing `c.setDoOutput(true);` ?

Comment: @WildCopper Hi i get the following Response Message.  Http request  failed: Method Not Allowed

Comment: As ρяσѕρєя K suggested, remove the c.setDoOutput(true) and try again. I use almost similar code and it works perfectly.

Comment: Ok thanks to you both. If one of you writes an answer i'll accept.